# Dynamic PHP If statement for filtering results

Tags: php, if-statement

I am currently building a class for directory/file handeling for a project I'm working on. To make it more flexible I would like to find a way to make a dynamic `if` statement to handle exclusions. I can see it being helpful elsewhere as well. I would like to make it so  `IF($file !=....`  were some thing like

```
PUBLIC $filter = '$file != "."....';

IF($filter)
```

So that I could set `$filter` in the main program just before calling `FileLib1\GetDirectory()`
currently I have the following inside of `GetDirectory()`

```
while ($file = readdir($handler)) 
{

    // if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
    //If $file !=  statement excludes things we dont want in the listing.  
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file !="0grp" && $file !="0ren" && $file != "unz.sh" && $file != "index.php" && $file != "galery.php" && $file != "forward.jpeg" && $file != "helper.html" && $file != "image.php" && $file != "reverse.jpeg") 
    {
        $results[] = $file;
    }

}
```

**I am updating the question with the few bits I had to learn along the way to more completely answer this question.**

```
$exclusions = new CustomHandler();
$exclusions->exclude(array(
  'cover.jpg',
  ));
$fileExclusions = $exclusions->getExclusions();
```

This is how I had to format the runtime code for the class to work.

```
public function getExclusions()
{
    return $this->excludes;
}
```

This was added at the end of the class to allow for returning the values from the class to a runtime variable for use in if statements like..

```
  if(!in_array($content, $fileExclusions)){ ... }
```

Comment: Both answers below are correct, I chose the one that was more class oriented as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you're building a class you can set a default variable, such as `$excluded`, which is an empty array. Then in the constructor of the class you can initialize your defaults and merge any custom ones passed in, like:

```
$handler = new CustomHandler(array('screen.jpg', 'stuff.png', 'script.sh'));
```

Such a implementation would look like below:

```
class CustomHandler {

    /*
     * Empty variable. Used to reference excluded variables during invoking and processing.
     */

    public $excluded = array();

    /*
     * @param $excludes - array
     * 
     */
     public function __construct($excludes = false)
     {
         //default exclusions here.
         $this->excludes = array(
             '0ren',
             'unz.sh'
             //etc....
         );
         if( is_array( $excludes ) ){
             $this->excludes = array_merge($this->excludes, $excludes);
         }
    }

    //other functions to process here
}
```

Also I just realized that if you want to leverage method chaining to keep the overhead down on the constructor. That example is below.

```
class CustomHandler {

    /*
     * Empty variable. Used to reference excluded variables during invoking and processing.
     */

    public $excluded = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this;        
    }

    /*
     * @param $excludes - array
     */
    public function exclude($excludes = false){
        //default exclusions here.
         $this->excludes = array(
             '0ren',
             'unz.sh'
             //etc....
         );
         if( is_array( $excludes ) ){
             $this->excludes = array_merge($this->excludes, $excludes);
         }
         return $this;
    }

    public function process(){
        echo 'Pre-process handler..';
        echo '<pre>', print_r($this->excludes, true),'</pre>';
    }
}

$handler = new CustomHandler();

$handler->exclude(array(
    'screen.jpg',
    'stuff.png',
    'script.sh'
))->process();
```

[And finally..here's a working example](https://eval.in/444452)

Comment: the last " $this->excludes = array_merge($this->excludes, $excludes); " is confusing to me. I am new to classes so I may not be understanding this properly but it would seem to be run after the fact rather than updating the excludes

Comment: In the first example, the exclude pattern is executed prior to any logic is performed in the class. In my second eample, I allow the exclude function to be ran independently, but method-chained, so that you can have it either way. Finally, the `$excludes` is passed as the last argument so that it may update any previous keys if they existed and matched (so your defaults can't be overwritten)

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this still.  Taking your 2nd example the process part is confusing.  I can see using this to make $handler an array and then using if(in_array($file, $handler)) i think.

Comment: The construct also confuses me in the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an approach similar to this -

```
$notArray = array('.', '..', '0grp', '0ren','unz.sh','index.php','galery.php','forward.jpeg','helper.html','image.php','reverse.jpeg');
if (in_array($file, $notArray)) {
    echo 'skipping ';
}
echo $file.PHP_EOL;
```

However, I suggest you reorganize your files such that the files of interest are all in one directory.

Or, use **glob** to request only those files whose name matches a specific pattern, for example:

```
$dataFiles = glob("*.dat");
```

Comment: That's part of what this is doing.  I never want . or .. and in my project I am importing data from another system in to mine so I am having to work around how things were done in that project.  I was hoping to use this to mask out static content or other unwanted items. I am unable to take the current system offline to modify things so a dynamic if would make life alot easier.

Comment: Then use **glob** to choose only those files you're interested in.

Comment: Took me a little bit to sort out but that's a nice way of doing it.  going to have to test and see about if (! in_array($file, $notArray))  works if so that will be a quick way of handling this.  The other answer seems to have a more flexable construction to it and seems to be the best general answer but both are good